# Controlling dictionary update with identical keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm merging a set of dictionaries, and two of them may contain the same key but different values. Currently, my simple code looks something like:

```
dictOne = {'income': 10000, 'name': 'John'}
dictTwo = {'income': 6000, 'job': 'plumber'}
resultsDict = {}
myList = [dictOne, dictTwo]
for i in myList:
    resultsDict.update(i)
```

The value of the income key in `resultsDict` will always be whatever the value was in the most recently added dictionary where the same key is present (in this case it would be 6000).

What is the easiest/most elegant way to control the update of a given duplicate key? For example, don't add the new key/value if the key is already present, or don't update the key's value if the value to be updated is larger than the one already in the dict I'm updating?

Comment: Well, what do you want the result to be when there are duplicate keys? -what is the requirement?  - what will the rest of the code expect?

Comment: @wwii the rest of the code will expect the result to be a single dictionary with no duplicate keys. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I already specified what might happen (e.g. don't add the new key/val or only update the new val if it's larger than the existing one)

Comment: You are asking us to tell you when it is correct to update/change the value of a duplicate key when consolidating dictionaries.  We don't know, your program's requirements would determine that. Does it matter?  If you update duplicate key values randomly, would it affect the program results?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to actually loop over all the dictionaries individually, check if the key is there, when it's not there or when it is but lower than the new value, update appropriately

```
for currDict in myList:

    for key, val in currDict.items():

        try:
            val = float(val)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        try:
            if resultsDict[key] < val:
                resultsDict[key] = val
        except KeyError:
            resultsDict[key] = val
```

**NOTE:** I change the nomenclature of `i` for readability

**UPDATE:** This code does NOT cover the case of when `val` does not contain numbers (or anything that can be `float`-ed).  You did not specify how you wanted that case to behave so this simply ignores that

Answer (score 0):

You could just add both keys and values into one dictionary.
dictTwo = {'incomeOne': 10000, 'incomeTwo': 6000,  etc...} then pull them out accordingly.